# I need a wire to pull about 20-30A in order to test a current sensor I've bought. How should I go about this?

Tags: wire, amperage

In order to test a sensor, I need to be able to consistently have a 20-30A DC line. I can buy any equipment needed, but I'm not 100% sure where to start. Any advice would be appreciated!

Edit: The sensor is a contactless ring sensor with a 4-20 mA output.

Comment: More information about your sensor would be helpful.

Comment: If it is a contactless sensor you can use n (e.g. 10) turns of a wire and only need 1/n-th (e.g. 2-3A) of current. That might simplify your undertaking.

Comment: If you are worried about a wire itself look at the [current limits](https://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm).  Look into the column for chassis wiring max current.  12 AWG wire is rated for 41 A.  12 AWG is a manageable wire gauge.  Or 3x 18 AWG in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Do you pass the current carrying wire through the ring sensor?

If so, just loop the wire several times through the ring. If you loop it 10 times through the ring the measured current will be 10 times the actual current through the wire.

This will allow you to use a lower current power supply for the test.

Answer (score 1):

Buy a lab power supply that has a 30 amp capacity. Most can be used in constant voltage or constant current mode. Set it to one or two volts. Connect a thick wire across the output. Set it to current limit at the desired current.

Power supplies that can put out this much current aren't cheap. https://www.tek.com/en/products/keithley/dc-power-supplies/2260b-series

Many will have a digital readout of the current. This may not be accurate enough for you if you are testing a sensor.

Comment: A great idea, but you don't need 30A at all. Simply create a 30 turn loop and you only need a 1A power supply. If the objective is to calibrate (rather than simply test) a sensor then you could use a FET Electronic DC load to set accurate current, again you only need 1A maximum so only a small power supply.